# WPF number of rectangle-array-element in ClickEvent needed

Tags: c#, wpf, events, canvas, rectangles

I'm currently porting a perl-tk-application to c# wpf. The application supplies a graphical interface with different timelines for different systems. The timelines consist of rectangles - each one representing a special event - that can be clicked for obtaining deeper information about the event. The rectangles have different sizes depending on the length of the event - so their sizes (width) are different and not predictable.
All I need now is the possibility to bind an event to each of the rectangles that - at least - lets me track back which rectangle was clicked. In Perl it was as easy as this:

```
$rectangle = $Canvas->create_rectangle( $x1, $y1 ,$x2 ,oy2 , -outline => "red", -fill => "red");
$Canvas->bind($rectangle, "<1>", sub {DoAction[$number]});
```

That means you can just put the event-binding after the element that needs to be clickable.
I've wasted the whole weekend in searching for a solution to do this in c# wpf... Important to know - I'm an absolut newbie in c#.
My code so far: I generated 10 rectangles via array. I want to pass the number of the rectangle-array to the ClickEvent. In the following example code the ClickEvent always prints out the highest index. I assume, there exists only one Event and I would need to generate a array of events...? What's the solution for this? In short words: Which rectangle (number) was clicked?

```
    private void ClickEvent (object sender, EventArgs e, int i) {
        var time = DateTime.Now;
        string name = ((Shape)sender).Name;
        Console.WriteLine("Rectangle click at " + time + " from " + name + " Rect. Nr." + i);
    }
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        int NumObjects = 10;
        Rectangle[] RectangleArray = new Rectangle[NumObjects];

        for (int i = 0; i < NumObjects - 1; i++) {
            RectangleArray[i] = new Rectangle();
            RectangleArray[i].Width = 50;
            RectangleArray[i].Height = 50;
            RectangleArray[i].Fill = Brushes.Red;
            Canvas.SetTop(RectangleArray[i], i * 50);
            Canvas.SetLeft(RectangleArray[i], i * 50);

            RectangleArray[i].MouseLeftButtonDown += (sender2, e2) => ClickEvent(sender2, e2, i);

            Canvas1.Children.Add(RectangleArray[i]);
        }
    }
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfRectangleEvent.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfRectangleEvent"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    Loaded="Window_Loaded">

<Grid>
    <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="666" Margin="-17,-20,0,0"
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="517"
    Name="Canvas1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">

    </Canvas>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the event handler method the sender object is the Rectangle which invokes the event.
So if you store the rectangles, you can find out the index of that rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

OK! Got it, this works:

```
    private void ClickEvent(object sender, EventArgs e, int i) {
        var time = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine("Rectangle click at " + time + " from Rect. Nr." + i);
    }
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        int NumObjects = 10;
        Rectangle[] RectangleArray = new Rectangle[NumObjects];

        for (int i = 0; i < NumObjects - 1; i++) {
            int index = i;
            RectangleArray[i] = new Rectangle();
            RectangleArray[i].Width = 50;
            RectangleArray[i].Height = 50;
            RectangleArray[i].Fill = Brushes.Red;
            Canvas.SetTop(RectangleArray[i], i * 50);
            Canvas.SetLeft(RectangleArray[i], i * 50);

            RectangleArray[i].MouseLeftButtonDown += (sender2, e2) => ClickEvent(sender2, e2, index);

            Canvas1.Children.Add(RectangleArray[i]);
        }
    }
```